# sort a view by Most Viewed, Most Favorited, Latest

Tags: views, flags

I have view which contains all nodes of a content type(article). default sort criteria of view is recent nodes. But i have three links Most Viewed, Most Favorited, Latest.I have to sort this view by clicking on these links .

I am making a node favorite by using flag module .

How can i achieve that .

Please Help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Create three different views, Most Viewed, Latest, Most favourite with display type block.
- For sorting by views, You need to enable statistics module.
- For sorting by latest, use post date sort filter in views.
- For sorting by favourite, flag module has integration with views. You can able to create a filter to sort by number of flags.
- Use [Quick Tabs](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module to group above three different view blocks as a single block and display it where ever needed.

Comment: Thanks Anil ! I am trying your solution . will let you know if it works ..

Comment: Anil i need one more favor, how can i render these tabs in my views template file . Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve it using VIEWS.

First of all enable **statistics module** and create 3 blocks Most Viewed, Most Favorited, Latest and Add required fields

[image]

- Views : Latest Block

  - Sort by POST DATE
  - [image]
- Views : Most Viewed Block

  - Enable statistics module and go to  `admin/config/system/statistics` configuration page and check **Count content views**

    [image]
  - Add the statistics counter field in VIEWS BLOCK if you want to see the count

    [image]
  - Add **Add filter criteria** to sort the VIEWS block to sort based on most Viewed

    [image]
- Views : Most Favorited Block

  - Add the relationship

    [image]

    [image]

    [image]
  - Add filter criteria to sort based on flags